# How can I use AdellePE Bold font in css?

Tags: fonts, css, front-end-development

I have a text whose font-family is `AdellePE Bold` I am wondering how can I use it in our CSS?

```
.blog-text
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 100px;
    color: rgb(254, 91, 31);
    font-family: AdellePE Bold ;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: .24em;
}
```

I am using the above code but unfortunately its not matching the font of the text.

Comment: How are you loading it? Is it a local font? loaded from a URL? hosted on your website?

Answer (score 5):

First and foremost: any font name that has a space should be enclosed in either single quotes `'` or double quotes `"` in CSS.

Be aware that a font you use this way in CSS will depend on the end user having exactly that font installed on their device. Unless you embed the font into the site using a technique like `@font-face`, end users without the correct font file will see their browser's default font.

For this reason, it is wise to add fallback fonts in order of preference. This is called a **font stack**:

```
.blog-text {
  font-family: 'AdellePE Bold', Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}
```

The browser will display the first named font that it can find on the user's machine to display. Font stacking is wise even when you use `@font-face`, to be prepared for the times that a browser or device doesn't support it.

An important caveat worth mentioning is that embedding the font file in the way that the `@font-face` technique requires, exposes it to free downloading—essentially having you re-publish the font. While it is possible to convert your font file into `@font-file` ready formats, it is very well possible that your font license does **not** allow you to republish in this way. Check your license.